# regex multiline search pattern

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have struggled to find an answer to this. Although I'm using C++ boost regex, if I just have a working expression I can adapt it (although I'll gratefully accept a boost-specific clue).

I have the following sample text:

```
----
this is a sample line -> various chars
another sample line (again 'might have different chars]
etc., etc.
----
more data
again anything in here.
more lines of text -> etc
etc. etc.
----
maybe only one line
```

and the trailing "----" is optional.

I've tried:

```
^-{4}\s(.*\s)*?(-{4})+
```

and variations, but I'm only getting the last line in my group 2, whereas I want all lines
following the 4 '-' chars in group 2, except if it is another line starting with 4'-' chars.

Answer (score 0):

Quantified capturing groups only capture the last instance. Make that group non-capturing, and wrap the entire quantified expression into a capturing group.

```
^-{4}\s((?:.*\s)*?)(-{4})+
       ^ ^^       ^
```

Also, I'm not sure what the purpose of `(-{4})+` is. You may mean this instead:

```
^-{4}\s((?:.*\s)*?)(?=-{4}|\s*$)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?= ... )` is a lookahead assertion. It asserts that immediately following the current position is either a `-{4}` or the end of the text (after possible whitespace).

Finally, you may want to make one tweak...

```
^-{4}\s+((?:.*\s+)*?)(?=-{4}|\s*$)
     ^          ^
```

...in case there are blank lines between your text.

Comment: @user2259541 - made some additional comments in an edit; take another look if you run into any problems.

Comment: You were correct about the end of the regex. Many thanks again! As for the blank line potential, although I have not seen this, IIUC it cannot hurt. Great; thank you!